# Getting all Chat Messages with c# using LiveChat API

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, api, livechat

I have managed to connect to LiveChat API using C# with my account and access key. I have included the LiveChat API in a c# console project with aid from here https://github.com/livechat/api-client-csharp. What I want to really do is get access to all chat messages by other agents so i can store them in data structures and push to my sql server. I tried this code from LIVECHAT API documentation and added a option to the menu list called getChatMessages and it returns a JSON FORMAT string stored in string variable. Now I want to access each element of the JSON format so i can store in data structure??

```
 public async Task getChatMessages()
 {

Dictionary<string, string> parameters = new Dictionary<string, string>();

 parameters.Add("date_from", "2017-10-27");

parameters.Add("query", "test");

string result = await Api.Archives.Get(parameters);
return await Api.Get(result);
}
```

This code below is the actual function that calls to API

```
public async Task<string> Get(Dictionary<string, string> parameters)
    {
        string uri = "";
        if (parameters != null && parameters.Count > 0)
        {
            foreach (var keyValuePair in parameters)
            {
                if (uri.Length == 0)
                {
                    uri = "chats?";
                }
                else
                {
                    uri += "&";
                }
                uri += string.Format("{0}={1}", keyValuePair.Key, HttpUtility.UrlEncode(keyValuePair.Value));
            }
        }

        return await Api.Get(uri);
    }
```

The value is returned in unstructured JSON format in a string variable. This is the response format; I used comma (,) as delimiter to write each separate element as new line to text file, so It was readable. What I really want is to access each element of a chat message so I can push to sql table format format. The below is JSON format the API gave in response.

```
{"chats":[{"type":"chat"
"id":"OYTHUUBLB2"
"tickets":[]
"visitor_name":"val"
"visitor_id":"S1509127853.f7c1666ec1"
"visitor_ip":"avl"
"visitor":{"id":"S1509127853.f7c1666ec1"
"name":"val"
"email":"val"
"ip":"76.71.60.221"
"city":"Brampton"
"region":"Ontario"
"country":"Canada"
"country_code":"CA"
"timezone":"America/Rainy_River"}
"agents":[{"display_name":"val"
"email":"val"
"ip":"val"}]
"supervisors":[]
"rate":"not_rated"
"duration":213
"chat_start_url":"val"
"group":[3]
"started":"val"
"pending":false
"tags":[]
"timezone":"America/Bogota"
"messages":[{"author_name":"val"
"text":"val"
"date":"val"
"timestamp":1509127958
"agent_id":"val"
"user_type":"agent"
"type":"message"
"welcome_message":true}
{"author_name":"val"
"text":"val"
"date":"val"
"timestamp":1509127976
"user_type":"visitor"
"type":"message"}
{"author_name":"val"
"text":"val"
"date":"val"
"timestamp":1509128147
"user_type":"visitor"
"type":"message"}]
"prechat_survey":[{"key":"Name:"
"value":"val"
"id":"148156886386907509"}
{"key":"E-mail:"
"value":"val"
"id":"148156886386907954"}
{"key":"Choose a department:"
"value":"val"
"id":"148156886386909015"}
{"key":"Question:"
"value":"I have another question"
"id":"val"}]
"events":[{"author_name":"val"
"text":"val"
"date":"val"
"timestamp":1509127958
"agent_id":"val"
"user_type":"agent"
"type":"message"
"welcome_message":true}
{"author_name":"val"
"text":"val"
"date":"val"
"timestamp":val
"user_type":"visitor"
"type":"message"}
{"author_name":"val"
"text":"val"
"date":"val"
"timestamp":val
"user_type":"val"
"type":"message"}
{"text":"val"
"date":"val"
"timestamp":val
"type":"event"
"user_type":"visitor"}]
"engagement":"immediate_start"
"started_timestamp":1509127958
"ended_timestamp":1509128171
"ended":"val"}
 ]
"total":1
"pages":1}
```

Comment: What is the definition of `does not work`? Do you get any error? What output you expect and what actual output you are getting?

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya, This is the error I'm getting=   Error: Not Found -404
Cannot GET /v2/%7B%22chats%22:[],%22total%22:0,%22:0,%22pages%22:0%7D

Comment: you need to refer API documentation to understand how to send parameter to API...

Comment: As per the API Documentation it should make request to `chats?\date_from=2013-01-23` but the error you shared does have any date_from information. Are you sure you are looking at the correct code? Did you debug the code? https://docs.livechatinc.com/rest-api/#get-list-of-chats

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya it seems to work when I used 1 of out chats keyword in test parameter  but the response Is all jumbled  and not readable. I see in the documentation it is in JSON format but that is not what I am seeing when results come back. Is there a fix to the code to allow the returned result to be proper readable format??

Comment: You can't change the way API returns the response. Can you share the jumbled up response you are getting and also tell what kind of response you expect?

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya  I wrote back the results to a text file to verify. and it does in fact returns in JSON format.  The same format in the sample response as that link you sent me  in  https://docs.livechatinc.com/rest-api/#get-list-of-chats Now I want to access each element, well the elements I want  and pass them to data structures probably a list so I can push them to SQL SERVER in Sql Table Form.  Each chat message would be a record..and those tag elements would be fields I want to push to a SQL TABLE. Just need some help now to access each element for each individual chat msg record.

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya the entire response is stored in JSON format but still is just a JSON format stored in a string variable. I want to be able to access the elements I want of each individual chat message, so I can push to SQL table format.